# Obtaining Drawable object from string in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I am trying to find a way to set an imageview via a string. It seems that getResources() is deprecated and I can't seem to find a fast way to pass a string and load an image to my imageView. I do not have any working or useful code to present, I am simply asking for methods to look into.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, this question makes no sense to me at all.  Can you point me to the doc for exactly which getResources is deprecated?  How exactly do you intend to convert a string into an image?

Comment: Here is an example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254100/how-to-set-an-imageviews-image-from-a-string

I have the names of the images I wish to access, so I wish to access them from drawable by their names.

Comment: I can't see anything in the Docs about `getResources()` being deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()

Comment: This is what I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22

Comment: `getDrawable(int id)` is deprecated as of API 22 (it has been superseded by `getDrawable(int id, Theme theme)`), but `getResources()` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by *theMatus* is correct. Drawables are accessed via an `int` identifier (i.e. `R.drawable.some_image` will have a corresponding `int` value). To convert a `String` to such a value, you would use `Resources.getIdentifier()`:

```
String mDrawableName = "some_image";
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

To access the `Drawable`, you would use `getResources().getDrawable(resId)`. `getResources()` is not deprecated by the way, although [`getDrawable(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int))technically is as of API 22 (it will still work). If you want to approach this correctly and get around the deprecation, you can use the following:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
private Drawable getDrawableForSdkVersion(int resId, Resources res) {

    Drawable drawable = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        drawable = res.getDrawable(resId, null);
    } else {
        drawable = res.getDrawable(resId);
    }

    return drawable;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

with API 22 'getResources()' is deprecated. You can use this instead, it also backward compatible so you can safely move on to this method.

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.<you_name_it>)
```

**Update:**

Also forgot to mention that you can use Picasso to load your strings (aiming to picture's path) into imageviews.

here a little example:

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("www.pictures.com/picture.jpg").into(imageView1);
```

you can make a little search about Picasso here: http://square.github.io/picasso/

not to mention but Stackoverflow Android app also uses this library, one of the must-have libraries in Android.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I access my images dynamically? I want to pass a string, not static

Comment: Am I allowed to use picasso commercially? I can't tell

Comment: where does your image come from?

Comment: Local, I have it saved in drawable

Comment: There is no statement that Picasso is not for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(currentActivity.this,R.drawable.your_image));
```

Actually theMatus answered your question. This code is for deprecated problem.