# How can I get the integer value of R.id.image?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, imageview

While using recycler views, I just want to pass the string values of resource id's of the images, but I know that it can't be done using the usual way, like we cannot pass a string in `setImageResource()`. But is there a way to convert the `R.id.anyImage` into its integer value?

Comment: what do you mean by passing string values? do you have string value like the name of the image?

Comment: if you have a resource name as a string you can get the resource id using `getIdentifier`

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5254100, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4313007, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737607, https://stackoverflow.com/q/13351003, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2414134.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no getImageResource() or getDrawableId(). But, You can create simple workaround by using the ImageView tags.

In onCreate():

```
imageView0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView0);
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

imageView0.setTag(R.drawable.apple);
imageView1.setTag(R.drawable.banana);

imageView2.setTag(R.drawable.cereal);
```

Then, if you like, you can create a simple function to get the drawable id:

```
private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) 
{
return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

Too easy.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks!!

Comment: click a upvote button on the answer if you think this is useful

Comment: I would love to but rep < 15. :(